# "Raw" conversion from double-UTF-8 to UTF-8 (or from UTF-8 to ANSI)

Tags: encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, iconv, cp1252

I am dealing with a legacy file that has been encoded twice using UTF-8. For example, the codepoint `ε` (`U+03B5`) should had been encoded as `CE B5` but has instead been encoded as `C3 8E C2 B5` (`CE 8E` is the UTF-8 encoding of `U+00CE`, `C2 B5` is the UTF-8 encoding of `U+00B5`).

The second encoding has been performed assuming the data was encoding in CP-1252.

To go back to the UTF-8 encoding I use the following (seemly wrong) command

```
iconv --from utf8 --to cp1252 <file.double-utf8 >file.utf8
```

My problem is that iconv seems unable to convert back some characters. More precisely, iconv is unable to convert characters whose UTF-8 representation contains a character that map to a **control character** in CP-1252. One examples is the codepoint `ρ` (`U+03C1`):

- its UTF-8 encoding is `CF 81`,
- the first byte `CF` is re-encoded to `C3 8F`,
- the second byte `81` is re-encoded to `C2 81`.

iconv refuses to convert `C2 81` back to `81`, probably because it does not know how to map that control character precisely.

```
echo -e -n '\xc3\x8f\xc2\x81' | iconv --from utf8 --to cp1252
�iconv: illegal input sequence at position 2
```

**How can I tell iconv to just perform the mathematical UTF-8 conversion without caring about the mappings?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code uses the low-level encoding functions of Ruby to force the rewriting of double encoded UTF-8 (from CP1525) into normal UTF-8.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

ec = Encoding::Converter.new(Encoding::UTF_8, Encoding::CP1252)

prev_b = nil

orig_bytes = STDIN.read.force_encoding(Encoding::BINARY).bytes.to_a
real_utf8_bytes = ""
real_utf8_bytes.force_encoding(Encoding::BINARY)

orig_bytes.each_with_index do |b, i|
    b = b.chr

    situation = ec.primitive_convert(b.dup, real_utf8_bytes, nil, nil, Encoding::Converter::PARTIAL_INPUT)

    if situation == :undefined_conversion
            if prev_b != "\xC2"
                    $stderr.puts "ERROR found byte #{b.dump} in stream (prev #{(prev_b||'').dump})"
                    exit
            end

            real_utf8_bytes.force_encoding(Encoding::BINARY)
            real_utf8_bytes << b
            real_utf8_bytes.force_encoding(Encoding::CP1252)
    end

    prev_b = b
end

real_utf8_bytes.force_encoding(Encoding::BINARY)
puts real_utf8_bytes
```

It is meant to be used in a pipeline:

```
cat $PROBLEMATIC_FILE | ./fix-double-utf8-encoding.rb > $CORRECTED_FILE
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo -e -n '\xc3\x8f\xc2\x81' | iconv --from utf8 --to iso8859-1
```

Windows-1252 differs from ISO-8859-1 in the 0x80-0x9F range. For example, in your case, 0x81 is U+0081 in ISO 8859-1, but is invalid in Windows-1252.

Check whether the rest of your data was misinterpreted as Windows-1252 or ISO 8859-1. Usually, ISO 8859-1 is more common.

Comment: This causes problems with other characters that are not mappable in latin1 but are in cp1252, for example ‰ `U+2030`. I am pretty sure that the intermediate encoding has been cp1252, but that does not matter in this case, as the UTF-8 conversion has been applied blindly to some bytes.

Comment: Can you give an example, in hex?

Comment: This cannot be translated using latin1: `\xc3\xa1\xc2\xbc\xe2\x82\xac`.

Comment: I see. Then the only thing I can suggest is to write some custom code that fixes this.